# Explanation or documentation of how this string replace lambda group function works

Tags: python, regex, pandas, string, replace

I have this function here which I use to replace the a string like this `'ABCDe.CO'` with `'ABCD-E.CO'` in a pandas dataframe.

I don't understand how the group(0) part works, I can't find any documentation on it. Could someone explain to me what this function does or where I can read up on it?

`(df.loc[df.country.eq('ST'), 'ticker'].str.replace('([a-z])', lambda x: '-'+x.group(0).upper()))`

Comment: `x` is the match data object found with a `([a-z])` regex. The whole matched text is turned to uppercase and prepended with `-`. Read [`re.sub` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), you will find *If repl is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of pattern. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.*

Comment: I tried doing `'ABCDe.CO'.replace('([a-z])',lambda x: '-'+x.group(0).upper())` but I get an error, it only seems to work in pandas, any idea why ?

Comment: Because you need a regex replacement, `re.sub`